# Format cell in google sheet to number WITHOUT changing it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a kinda big google sheet. Around 20k rows. One of the cells in these rows contains always a 17 digit number. I automatically adding new rows via the google API with the nodeJS package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet).

Here is my problem, everything works fine if the last two digits in the number arent two zeros. If its 12345678912345678 then the "automatically" formating works fine. It shows it as it is and I can read it with the NodeJS package as it is.

But if its 12345678912345600 then its gets automatically converted to 1,23456E+16.
Now I want to convert it back to "normal". Thought kinda easy, just use format "text" and it should be displayed correctly. I dont care if its a number or a text, I can handle that on my side of the script. But formating it to text change the value of the cell to 1,23456E+16. Not what I want.

Okay, then convert it to a number, no problem. The normal default number formats doesnt fit (Since I dont want any . or , or decimal or anything, just the plain number. Custom number  format it is. So I select custom number format and even the first example is what I want. So I select the format 0. Its just display the number without anything. Works exactly as I want.

Okay, lets do it for all of the 20k rows. I have roughly 1k rows with a double zero at the end. So I select the complete column, custom number format 0 and done?
Nope... Next problem. If you convert a number with more than 15 digits, every digit after the 15th digit get converted to 0. So I change all my other rows.
I could go and select all the affected one thousand rows by hand and just convert these rows, but yeah... one thousand rows...

Isnt there any way to convert these numbers just to display the number? Without changing it?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the number as text using ' in front of the number?

Comment: Yes, that fix the problems for new rows and is already done. But I still have the thousand old rows that need to be changed

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the format `NUMBER` to `#` to display the plain number:

A sample script:

```js
const changeFormatNumber = async () => {
    const auth = await getOAuthClient()
    const sheet = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth })
    const prop = await sheet.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
        spreadsheetId: '<SPREADSHEET_ID>',
        requestBody: {
            requests: [
                {
                    repeatCell: {
                        fields: 'userEnteredFormat.numberFormat',
                        range: {
                            startRowIndex: 0,
                            startColumnIndex: 0,
                            endColumnIndex: 1,
                            endRowIndex: 100
                        },
                        cell: {
                            "userEnteredFormat": {
                                "numberFormat": {
                                    "type": "NUMBER",
                                    "pattern": "#"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },

                }
            ]
        }
    })
    console.log(prop)
}
```

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image]

###### **Documentation**

- [`Basic Formatting`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting#set_a_custom_datetime_or_decimal_format_for_a_range)
- [`Cell Data`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#celldata)